# Using Trig. identities find the exact value of $\cos(105^{\circ})$

Tags: trigonometry

The answer states its $\dfrac {\sqrt {2}}{2}$ but im not sure how they have obtained this answer?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The cosine of $105^o$ should be negative

Comment: in radians - also negative

Comment: $105=60+45$. $\quad $

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac {\sqrt 2}{2}$ is *not* the answer, but some hints to point you the right way...

1. The cosine function is negative in the second quadrant.
2. $\cos (a+b) = \cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b$.
3. Use lulu's suggestion above with #2.

Answer (score 1):

Or use
$$
\cos(105^∘)=-\sin(15^∘)=-\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(30^∘)}2}=-\frac12\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}=...
$$